# How do I stop Visual Studio (devenv) accessing lots of temp files in AppData

Tags: visual-studio-2010, file-io

I was trying to work out while compiles are taking so long, so I started “Process Monitor” and got a few unexpected results.

While a build is going on Visual Studio creates lots of temp files in C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp.  The issue is that the C drive is a normal disk drive, but we have all our source code on a SSD, so it would be faster if we could get Visual Studio to use the SSD as much as possible.

Comment: Change the TEMP environment variable.

Comment: @HansPassant please convert you comment into an answer to I can accept it

Comment: No way.  Telling programmers that wasting their SSD on a bunch of small short-lived files that easily fit in the file system cache never goes over well.  You can post your own answer.